# Filter_input with Post string failing

Tags: php, post, filter

I'm not having the desired response when I apply filter_input.

The program im mantaining used to have:

```
$somePostcode = isset($_POST['somecode'])? $_POST['somecode']: null;
```

And I turned it into:

```
$somePostcode = ($somePostcode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'somecode') ) ? $somePostcode : null;
```

The results dont match; I'm getting string(0)"" for the original (i should get this result). And i get NULL for the filtered result.

Why is this failing, and how can i fix it?
I have tried with FILTER_DEFAULT, and most of other filters but cant make it match. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to take the `somecode` string instead of "codigoSolicitud" `$codigoSolicitud = ($codigoSolicitud = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'somecode') ) ? $codigoSolicitud : null;`

Comment: @MarkusZeller edited for clarification. My objective is to replace the upper code for the one filtered